# How to call/insert legend created by GetLegendGraphic request url of GeoServer on web-page?

Tags: geoserver, web-mapping, legend, html, web-service

I have followed the steps as mentioned on in the [GeoServer Documentation for GetLegendGraphic](https://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/services/wms/get_legend_graphic/index.html)

Now as I click over it, it gives out an image of the legend on the next web-page
[image: Legend]
and I have added this in the HTML as

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://localhost:8080/geoserver/agrodss/wms?REQUEST=GetLegendGraphic&VERSION=1.0.0&FORMAT=image/png&WIDTH=20&HEIGHT=20&LAYER=agrodss:Rainfall">
    <layout>
        <decoration type="legend" affinity="top,right" offset="0,0" size="auto"/>
    </layout>
```

I usually work at back-end and front-end is not my domain, so I am not sure how to proceed after this.

Can someone tell, How to call this URL request in the HTML so that it can appear on the webpage?

Comment: you want to get the legends displayed on the same page instead of a new page?

Comment: @Yogesh Chavan Yes, on the same page, where layer is showing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That URL returns an image so you include it in your web page in the same way as any other image `<img src='http://.....?request=getLegendGraphic'/>`